# PHP Using $this->load Fatal Error

Tags: php, this

Cant seem to wrap my head around $this!

I am trying to emulate a codeigniter function of loading views but i am obviously missing something.

```
class Load{

    public function __construct(){

    }

    public function view(){
        echo "Hello";
    }

    public function files(){

    }

    public function plugins(){

    }

}


$this->load->view();
```

This throws the following

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context

However when i use:

```
$load = new Load;
$load->view();
```

I get the expected response. Hello

Why does it work in Codeigniter but not in my simple script?

Ive already googled and searched SO..

Comment: Ask yourself this question: what object should `$this` resolve to in your first code example?

Comment: You can't use $this not in class context

Comment: To clear up the previous comments, `$this` refers to an instantiated object, and can only be used within that object. Or to say it differently, `$this` is shorthand for the current object. In your first example, `$this` is outside your class context, and you have not created an instance of the load class.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that even in CodeIgniter the exact same code would not work. You must be using it within an object context.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you use **$this** not in a class. So it is really not an object.

You should create the object of class before use it.

Or if you want to use it in other class, just do something like that:

```
class PreLoad
{
    public load;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load = new Load();
    }

    public function show()
    {
        $this->load->view();
    }
}

(new PreLoad())->show();
```